# can't run swig tutorial for python

Tags: c, python-3.x, gcc, swig

I have tried to no avail to run swig python tutorial, I have checked many similar questions but none solves my issue, I am using

windows *, 64 bit

SWIG Version 4.0.2

Compiled with i686-w64-mingw32-g++ [i686-w64-mingw32]

Configured options: +pcre

The example in particular deals with a gcd function written in C;

```
/* File : example.c */

/* A global variable */
double Foo = 3.0;

/* Compute the greatest common divisor of positive integers */
int gcd(int x, int y) {
  int g;
  g = y;
  while (x > 0) {
    g = x;
    x = y % x;
    y = g;
  }
  return g;
}
```

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

extern int gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
```

I ran `swig -python example.i`

But whenever I run `gcc -c -fpic example.c -IC:\Users\Moses\anaconda3\include`

```
example_wrap.c: In function '_wrap_gcd':
example_wrap.c:2886:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gcd'; did you mean 'gcvt'? [-Wimplicit-function-decla
ration]
   result = (int)gcd(arg1,arg2);
                 ^~~
                 gcvt
example_wrap.c: In function 'Swig_var_Foo_set':
example_wrap.c:2901:5: error: 'Foo' undeclared (first use in this function)
     Foo = (double)(val);
     ^~~
example_wrap.c:2901:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
example_wrap.c: In function 'Swig_var_Foo_get':
example_wrap.c:2912:37: error: 'Foo' undeclared (first use in this function)
   pyobj = SWIG_From_double((double)(Foo));
```

I only get the example.o file, whereas the example_wrap.o file is missing, almost definitely because of the error, I tried compiling it anyways with `ld -shared example.o /c/users/moses/Anaconda3/python37.dll /c/Windows/System32/msvcr120.dll -o _example.pyd`
But on attempt to import the example.py file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\moses\cGraphy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import example

  File "C:/Users/moses/example.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _example

ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__example)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example.i file needs to add the exports to the wrapper, as well as process them by SWIG:

```c
%module example

// this section is copied directly into the generated wrapper, so the functions
// can be found when example_wrap.c is linked with example.c
%{
extern int gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
%}

// This tells SWIG to write wrappers for these exports.
extern int gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
```

If you don't want to double up the definition, you can also use:

```c
%module example

// inline inserts into wrapper *and* SWIG wraps it.
%inline %{
extern int gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
%}
```

Example with this example.i:

```py
>>> import example
>>> example.cvar.Foo
3.0
>>> example.gcd(35,14)
7
```

I use MSVC instead of gcc, with these commands:

```
swig -python example.i
cl /LD /W3 /Fe_example.pyd /Ic:\python39\include example_wrap.c example.c -link /libpath:c:\python39\libs
```